# FullCalendar: How can i display an icon on each day of the month using the function DayRender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am building a calendar via [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io).

I would like to display a small icon img for each day of the the current month. regardlees to any events. (lets say i dont have events at all).
i would like to use the DayRender function. if that possible

here is the impletetion of my calendar so far:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var json_backgrundColor ={"1":"#f1f9ef","2":"#edf5f9","3":"#edf5f9","4":"#f7fafc","5":"#f7fafc","6":"#f7fafc","7":"#f7fafc","8":"#f7fafc","9":"#edf5f9","10":"#edf5f9","11":"#f7fafc","12":"#f7fafc","13":"#f7fafc","14":"#f7fafc","15":"#f7fafc","16":"#edf5f9","17":"#edf5f9","18":"#f7fafc","19":"#f7fafc","20":"#f7fafc","21":"#f7fafc","22":"#f7fafc","23":"#edf5f9","24":"#f1f9ef","25":"#ffdfdf","26":"#ffdfdf","27":"#f1f9ef","28":"#f1f9ef","29":"#f1f9ef","30":"#f1f9ef","31":"#f1f9ef"};

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
            },

            defaultView: 'month',
    dayRender: function ( date, cell) {
    var cellDate = date.format('D');
    if(!cell.hasClass('fc-other-month')) {    
        cell.css('background-color', json_backgrundColor[cellDate]);  
    }else {
            cell.css('background-color', '#ffffff');  
            }  
},
 
        });
        
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m53jbwx0/4/

anyone know how can i do that?

Comment: Is the image same for all?

Comment: in my final product no but for the sake of this question yes!

Comment: also, i may want to display 2 icons.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need something like this?

```
dayRender: function ( date, cell) {
cell.prepend('<i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mnjsjs6p

Comment: Is there a way to do this after events render?

Comment: @KrzysztofKaźmierczak is there anyway to display that in the controller side of c#? Like inside the snippet below?

Comment: `var absentEventList = from e in absentDates
    select new {
                    id = EnrollNumber,
                  title = "Absent",
                  start = ((DateTime)e.Date).ToString("s"),
                   end = ((DateTime)e.Date).ToString("s"),
                   someKey = EnrollNumber,
                   borderColor = "#ffffff",
                   color = "#fa0303",
                   allDay = false
                   };
                 var absentRows = absentEventList.ToArray();
                return Json(absentRows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: aria-hidden="true" was awesome