# How can I render a SVG in dayRender method of FullCalendar 4.x in a React app

Tags: reactjs, svg, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

For my react component, it uses FullCalendar and I want to provide a custom dayRender method so that if the date matches a certain date, I add a special SVG to that day cell.

Right now, I've imported the svg using code below:

```
import svg from 'Assets/special.svg';
```

My dayRender code looks like this:

```
const dayRender = (dayRenderInfo) => {
  if (moment(dayRenderInfo.date).format(dateFormat) === myDate) {
    // How do I render my svg?
  }
}
```

The issue is, I know we have to modify dayRenderInfo.el to add additional DOMNodes. However, my svg, when I inspect it using console.log is just a file name.

I think I need to render the svg somehow as a DOMNode and then append it to dayRenderInfo.el.

What's the right way to do this?

I've seen this post but I've looked into prepend and unfortunately, IE does not support this feature. [FullCalendar: How can i display an icon on each day of the month using the function DayRender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906572/fullcalendar-how-can-i-display-an-icon-on-each-day-of-the-month-using-the-funct)

Comment: Are you using svg at any other place in your app ?

Comment: No, this is the first time we are using it. The first thing I look for are existing examples though :)

Comment: There are couple of things (not giving it as answer as I am not sure which). 1) You can access filename,  so, add it as src in img tag. Can work but you wont be able to get full benefit of svg
2)  Sometimes issue can be on svg loading (will have to clear svg from webpack file loader)
3) CreateReactApp comes built in with SVGLoader as components,  You can use the package it uses (svgr) I guess